# Not getting expected results in IF statement, when referencing another cell also with an IF statement

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, sumifs

Issue, I'm looking for a result in one cell based on results on another cell where both cells are using IF statements.  The expected result is not displayed.

**Example**

Cell N14 is using a SUMIF formula to add the number of hours a person worked.

- In this issue, the result is zero (0).
- The result of the SUMIF on false is "", showing the cell blank

Formula

- =SUMIFS([Column_Hours_Worked],[Column_Name],[Name],[Column_Date],[Date],"","")
- *The formula I know works, as seen in cell N13.*

Cell O14 uses an IF statement, and returns an "X" if N14 is less than eight (8))

- =IF(N14>=8,"","X")

The N14 cell seems to work fine, as I observe the cell is blank.
- This is expected.

The O14 cell is not displaying the expected "X".

**Troubleshooting**

- I can manually enter zero (0) into N14, which causes the expected "X" in O14.
- I modified the SUMIF false result from blank ("") to ("0.0"), and did not see the expected "X" in O14.
- - O.O was observed in the N14 cell, as the SUMIF resulted in a false statement, or ("0.0")

**Background**

- I've created a spreadsheet to track the number of hours people work on a given day.
- I'd like to quickly identify when, in this example, less than 8 hours is worked.
- N14 = The number of hours worked.
- O14 = A flag ("X") at less than 8 hours.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I recreated a spreadsheet with your formulas and some basic data. When I removed the last two arguments from your N14 formula it worked for me (see below).

```
=SUMIFS([Column_Hours_Worked],[Column_Name],[Name],[Column_Date],[Date])
```

Is there a specific reason you'd like the SUMIFS to return "" instead of 0? In fact, I can't get SUMIFS to work with those last two arguments. You mentioned you a sumif on false argument but I don't believe the sumif function has an input for 'if false return this'. If you want that you'll have to nest SUMIFS inside an IF formula (like below) and then you can combine the N14 and O14 formulas.

```
=IF(SUMIFS([Column_Hours_Worked],[Column_Name],[Name],[Column_Date],[Date]<=8,"X","")
```

Comment: Please add  a few tags like "Spreadsheet" or "GoogleSheets" so that your question can be viewed by experts in that tag.